# Sorting and amalgamating in XQUERY

Tags: xml, xquery

I am having difficulty in sorting a set of XML based on some amalgamation rules that I need to apply. I am doing this in XQuery 1.0 and have been playing around the the distinct-values function, but finding it hard to relate all the records I need too.

The logic I'm trying to apply is

- There needs to be one occurrence of each combination that exists for frequency and payer and where contribution type is the same.
- The one occurrence is the instance of that combination that has the most recent date
- Where details appear on the same record with the same, most recent date, date, payer and frequency then they need to be amalgamated so that the amount shown for that frequency and payer of that particular date is the total amount paid on that date.
- If more than on record exists within the list then the details need to be amalgamated to arrive at the instance of that combination that has the most recent date.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
     <transaction_history>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-12-31</date>
           <payer>Employer</payer>
           <amount>5042.38</amount>
           <frequency>Quarterly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-12-31</date>
           <payer>Employer</payer>
           <amount>4676.94</amount>
           <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type B" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-09-08</date>
           <payer>Employer</payer>
           <amount>4317.52</amount>
           <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-12-31</date>
           <payer>Employer</payer>
           <amount>9393.11</amount>
           <frequency>Quarterly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-10-02</date>
           <payer>Employee</payer>
           <amount>3944.49</amount>
           <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type B" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-12-31</date>
           <payer>Employee</payer>
           <amount>3675.85</amount>
           <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type B" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-10-02</date>
           <payer>Employee</payer>
           <amount>3385.69</amount>
           <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
        <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
           <date>2015-12-31</date>
           <payer>Employee</payer>
           <amount>7369.64</amount>
           <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </contribution_transaction>
     </transaction_history>
```

In the example of

```
<contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
       <date>2015-12-31</date>
       <payer>Employer</payer>
       <amount>5042.38</amount>
       <frequency>Quarterly</frequency>
    </contribution_transaction>
<contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
       <date>2015-12-31</date>
       <payer>Employer</payer>
       <amount>5042.38</amount>
       <frequency>Quarterly</frequency>
    </contribution_transaction>
```

would result in:

```
 <contribution_transaction contribution_type="Type A" currency="GBP">
       <date>2015-12-31</date>
       <payer>Employer</payer>
       <amount>10084.76</amount>
       <frequency>Quarterly</frequency>
    </contribution_transaction>
```

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple `contribution_transaction`s with the same `frequency`, `payer` and `date`?

Comment: Hi Leo, then the amounts would need to be summed and then result in just one contribution_transaction. I actually need to factor in the contribution type attributes as well, which I've realised I forgot to include.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two nested groupings one after the other:

```
for $frequency in distinct-values(//frequency)
let $contrib := //contribution_transaction[frequency = $frequency]
for $payer in distinct-values($contrib/payer)
let $res := $contrib[payer = $payer]
let $min-date := min($res/date/xs:date(.))
return <result frequency="{$frequency}" payer="{$payer}">{
  (: do something clever with the relevant transactions here :)
  $res[xs:date(date) = $min-date]
}</result>
```

Since your date format is ordered correctly with lexicographic sorting order, you can also just compare the strings directly:

```
for $frequency in distinct-values(//frequency)
let $contrib := //contribution_transaction[frequency = $frequency]
for $payer in distinct-values($contrib/payer)
let $res := $contrib[payer = $payer]
let $min-date := min($res/date/string())
return <result frequency="{$frequency}" payer="{$payer}">{
  (: do something clever with the relevant transactions here :)
  $res[date = $min-date]
}</result>
```

Since your Processor seems to only support `node()`s as argument to `fn:min(...)`, you can use this quick replacement:

```
declare function local:min($seq) {
  local:min((), $seq)
};

declare function local:min($min, $seq) {
  if(empty($seq)) then $min
  else (
    let $first := $seq[1], $rest := $seq[position() > 1]
    return (
      if($min < $first) then local:min($min, $rest)
      else local:min($first, $rest)
    )
  )
};

(: example usage :)
local:min(('B', 'A', 'b'))
```

Comment: Do you think I need to strip out the hyphens in the date before passing them into the min() function, don't think it'll covert to a double otherwise?

Comment: In my query I convert it to an `xs:date`, a date format natively supported by XQuery. Comparing two strings will always be done lexicographically; if you want to compare them as `xs:double`s you have to explicitly convert at least one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I seem to be getting an error when trying this:{err}XP0004 [{bea-err}XP0004b]: Found type mismatch in expression. Only empty sequence satisfies type checking rules. Expected type: node*. 
 Actual type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date*

Comment: Strange... Can you try out the second query in my edited answer?

Comment: Still get an error, not sure why it's complaining. :: err}XP0004 [{bea-err}XP0004b]: Found type mismatch in expression. Only empty sequence satisfies type checking rules. Expected type: node*. 
 Actual type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string*

Comment: The only place where a sequence of strings `xs:string*` occurs is inside `min(...)`, which should definitely work on strings. Can you replace the fifth line with `let $min-date := min($res/date)` and see if that works? Which XQuery processor do you use?

Comment: I get err XP0021 "31-01-27" can not cast to XML schema double. The XQuery engine is the underlying one on the Oracle Service Bus (11g). I think its a custom built one by BEA.

Comment: Since your implementation of the `min(...)` function seems to (erroneously) only accept nodes and -- as I re-discovered -- has to convert all `xs:untypedAtomic` values to `xs:double` before comparing them, the only solution I see is to re-implement `min` as a user-defined function in XQuery. By the way, which time format is used in your data? `"31-01-27"` is not an ISO-8601 date.

Comment: It's just a custom date format expected by an end user system. Yeah I couldn't for the life of me get around the fact it always resolved to comparing xs:doubles. Do you know of any already written user defined min functions on the web anywhere? Thanks Leo.

Comment: I added a replacements for `min(...)` to my answer, you can adapt it to compare your dates correctly. I have no way of testing it inside Oracle, but I hope it works there, too -- XQuery functions seem to be supported at least.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I'm jumping between different tasks at the moment, but will give this a try soon and let you know how I got on. Much appreciated.